# Image button created from JLabel is not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a buttom from an image on the JFrame using the ImageIcon and the addMouseListener that will replace the current image with another image by clicking it.

```
static JPanel jp = new JPanel();
final JLabel jl = new JLabel();
final JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image1.jpg");
    jl.setIcon(image);
    jp.add(jl);
    jf.add(jp); 
    jf.validate();

    JLabel button = new JLabel(image);
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            jl.setIcon( null );
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image2.jpg");
            jl.setIcon(image);
        }
    });
```

The GUI is displayed with image1.jpg, but the button does not work at all and I can't even test whether the replacement from image1 to image2 works. GUI will not do anything even if I attempt to click the image1.jpg displayed on the window.

Edit: Adjusted JLabel varaible to be final for now. Other similar questions intimate that this method should be working but I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You should use an `ActionListener` for buttons.

Comment: I'm just trying to have the image clickable to command an action. Not really sure ActionListener works with JLabel either.

Comment: What class type is your "button" variable? Please show how it is declared and initialized. Your title suggests it's a JLabel, and if so, the variable name is highly misleading as it suggests that it is in fact a JButton or something similar. Consider clarifying your question.

Comment: Edited. The variable for the button is JLabel.

Comment: Please don't give a JLabel object the name "button". Again, this is misleading.

Comment: It looks like you've added a MouseListener to the JLabel called "button", which I don't see added to the panel.  Are you clicking on the JLabel called "jl" thinking that it's "button" instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Not really sure ActionListener works with JLabel either.

No you can't add an ActionListener to a JLabel. An easier approach is to make a JButton look like a JLabel, then you can add the ActionListener to the button:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.addActionListener(...);
```

> but the button does not work at all

A mouse click is generated when a mousePressed and mouseReleased is received for the same mouse point. So if you move the mouse slightly the event will not get generated. Instead listen for the mousePressed() event.